# SQLite query doesn't return reselts after using a new database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I added a new .sqlite database to my XCode project which I want to use instead of the previous .sqlite3 database. My problem now is that the items Array stays empty. What could be the problem? Do I have to use a .sqlite3 file?
the 'statement' variable stays '0x00000000' I think this is the problem.

```
@implementation DatabaseModel {

    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
}

-(void) openDb {

    int result = sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"Fehler beim Öffnen der Datenbank");
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Datenbank erfolgreich geöffnet");
}

-(NSMutableArray *) getStops {

   NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   const char *sql = "SELECT name FROM stops";

   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {

       while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
           NSString *message = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
           [items addObject:message];
       }
       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   }
   return items;
}
```

Comment: You need to open the database before you can use it.

Comment: Does `sqlite3_prepare_v2` even return SQLITE_OK??  You have no logging or error checking in there to know what's going on.

Comment: @rmaddy the database is already open

Comment: @HotLicks but it worked with the other database

Comment: But your code shows you creating and using an initialized `database` variable.

Comment: So you're saying that you have no idea whether `prepare` took an error or not?  Have you done ANYTHING to debug this?

Comment: @HotLicks no prepare doesn't return SQLITE_OK and I think because the 'statement' stays '0'.

Comment: So what is the return code??  And what does `sqlite3_errmsg` report when the return code is bad??  (This is very basic debugging you should have already done before posting.)

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for your support. I deleted the app on the simulator and now it works perfect. I'm sorry for not being able for that basic debugging.